# Excel Office.js - Enable/Disable Multiple Context Menu Items on right click

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, ribbonx, excel-web-addins

I'm working on a new feature for an existing Excel office add-in. This feature requires a new context menu item and Sub-menu Items under the menu item.

**I want to enable/disable the Sub-Menu Item based on the worksheet or a specific cell within a sheet.**

Can someone please let me know if there is such a feature available with Excel Office JS?

I am aware that there is such an option for Ribbons inside a Custom Tab but I dont see any documentation for Contextual Menu(Right Click)

```
    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="ContextMenu">
                      <OfficeMenu id="ContextMenuCell">
                        <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="Menu">
                                            <Label resid="Dropdown.Label" />
                                            <Supertip>
                                                <Title resid="Dropdown.Label" />
                                                <Description resid="Dropdown.Tooltip" />
                                            </Supertip>
                                            
                                            <Items>
                                                <Item id="Menu.Item1">
                                                    <Label resid="Item1.Label"/>
                                                    <Supertip>
                                                        <Title resid="Item1.Label" />
                                                        <Description resid="Item1.Tooltip" />
                                                    </Supertip>
                                                    
                                                <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                                    <FunctionName>signOff</FunctionName>
                                                </Action>
                                           <Enabled>false</Enabled>
                                                </Item>
                                                <Item id="Menu.Item2">
                                                <Label resid="Item2.Label"/>
                                                <Supertip>
                                                    <Title resid="Item2.Label" />
                                                    <Description resid="Item2.Tooltip" />
                                                </Supertip>
                                                
                                           <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                                <FunctionName>signOff2</FunctionName>
                                            </Action>
                                            </Item>
                            
                                            </Items>
                                        </Control>
                      </OfficeMenu>
                  </ExtensionPoint>
```

**EDIT 1**

AS per the suggestion below, I tried using the same code which OfficeJS documentation is suggesting for Enabling/Disabling Ribbon Buttons.

**My Code:**

```
async function signOff(args) {
  console.log("SignOff 1 started");
  Office.ribbon.requestUpdate({
    tabs: [
        {
            id: 'ContextMenuCell',
            controls: [
                {
                    id: 'Menu.Item1',
                    enabled: true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
  args.completed();
}
Office.actions.associate("signOff", signOff);
```

But I get the following error

```
  Uncaught (in promise) RichApi.Error: ControlIdNotFound
    at new n (excel-win32-16.01.js:25:257638)
    at i.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (excel-win32-16.01.js:25:321804)
    at excel-win32-16.01.js:25:319867
```

The requestupdate() method of the OfficeJS, which on the first look makes it pretty clear that this is for Ribbon as it is supposed to be called using `Office.ribbon.requestUpdate(input: RibbonUpdaterData)`

**Just in case my requirement isn't very clear.**

I have the below 'Sub-Menu 1' and 'Sub-Menu 2' items in my Contextual Menu.
[image: My Contextual Menu(Right-Click)]

**I want to enable/disable these submenus based on different business requirements** i.e. based on worksheet or based on cell or cell range etc.

**EDIT 2**

*Can we at least separate the submenu items like how Excel provides for Paste options?* refer the image below

[image: Menu Group Label]

*Can we add a separator between 2 sub-menu items like how excel provides for menu items?* refer image below

[image: Group Separator]

Comment: What is your current implementation of dynamic enabled/disabled for context menu items?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I've added my implementation in my Edit 1.

Comment: @WorksOnMyLocal How did you achieve the feature about icon for context menu? I tried to add `Icon` section, but it did not show up in right click menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether you deal with a context menu or custom ribbon tab. You can customize context menus in Office web add-ins:

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="ContextMenu">
  <OfficeMenu id="ContextMenuCell">
    <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="ContextMenu2">
            <!-- information about the control -->
    </Control>
    <!-- other controls, as needed -->
  </OfficeMenu>
```

If you want a custom button or menu item to be disabled when the Office application launches, you specify this in the manifest. Just add an `Enabled` element (with the value false) immediately below (not inside) the `Action` element in the declaration of the control.

If you want to change the state dynamically you need to use the [requestUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ribbon?view=common-js&preserve-view=true#office-office-ribbon-requestupdate-member(1)) method of the `Office.Ribbon` interface, see [Change the state in response to an event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands#change-the-state-in-response-to-an-event) for more information. Read more about supported ribbon extensibility in the [Enable and Disable Add-in Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands) and [Create custom contextual tabs in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/contextual-tabs) articles.

Note, you can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

Comment: I've updated my OP with the implementation you've suggested, though I was skeptical about it working as the requestUpdate() is a Ribbon method and takes in RibbonUpdaterData as input.   

But I need to update the Contextual Menu (Sub-Menu to be more specific). 

Can you please let me know how (if) you were able to successfully Enable/Disable Sub-menus using OfficeJS?

Comment: Try to post that as an issue to https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues . Context menus use the same technology as the controls on the ribbon (previously called the Ribbon UI), not it is called the Fluent UI.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will do that. But do you think I've used their code correctly? As you've mentioned it shouldn't matter if its Ribbon or Contextual menu, can you please let me know if you were successful in implementing such a scenario?

Comment: I've developed similar scenarios in COM add-ins where it works correctly, so I expect to get it working the same for web add-ins. MS has never stated that it is not supported for context menus. If you have any issues with your implementation you need to post it to the GitHub repo.

Comment: Can we group the Sub-menu Items? Or have a separator between different submenu items? Please refer my Edit 2 to understand what I mean,

Comment: Instead of constantly editing original posts with given answers you need to post a new question so SO users may recognize questions and answers easily.